# Access <select> onChange in Marionette ItemView

Tags: javascript, jquery, marionette

I have a Marionette ItemView like this:

```
List.Chart = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#chart-template",
    className: "block container-fluid first",

    onRender: function () {
      // Do a few things
    },
});
```

The template has a `<select id="filter">` tag with a few options in it. I would like to access the value of the `<select>` tag when a user clicks it and there has been a change. I'm new to Marionette. I tried a few ways but none got me the value. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You will not want to override render in your marionette view, instead you should take advantage of `onRender`

http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.itemview.html#render--onrender-event

As far as knowing when a user has click or changed the input you will want to take advantage of the events hash.
http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.view.html#viewevents

Which actually comes from backbone.

So it will look like this:

```
List.Chart = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#chart-template",
    className: "block container-fluid first",
    events: {
      "click #filter": "doSomething",
      "change #filter": "doSomething"
    },

    doSomething: function() {}
});
```

For extra points you should DRY up the event binding and take advantage of the @ui interpolation that backbone.marionette gives you for free.

```
List.Chart = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#chart-template",
    className: "block container-fluid first",
    ui: {
      "filter": "#filter"
    },
    events: {
      "click @ui.filter": "doSomething",
      "change @ui.filter": "doSomething"
    }
});
```